# I managed to install the OS, but I can't see anything in my monitor since it says "not supported resolution"

Tags: screen, monitor

My computer screen is ATVIO brand, but when I used another screen (Samsung) the OS works fine, can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I've had these problems before. What I had to do is that I connected a screen which was compatible, I lowered the resolution to 800x600, and then I connected my first screen.

I'm sure you could use other methods to solve the problem, such as entering the system through recovery mode and edit the resolution from there. You can do this by typing `rm ~/.config/monitors.xml` from a terminal, or from the recovery mode.
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Resetting_an_out-of-range_resolution

You could also try another type of graphical connection (eg. HDMI/DVI instead of VGA).